# Python Multidimensional Matrix Definition indexing Error

Tags: python

```
n = 5
L = 6
Cache = [[-1 for x in range(n+1)] for y in range(L+1)]
print(Cache[5][6])
```

The above code gives the below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/globetrekker/Documents/CS5050/Assignment3/temp.py", line11, in <module>
print(Cache[5][6])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am new to Python. So I don't understand how to rectify this error as I don't understand why can't I index into Cache[5][6]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print(Cache[5]) #[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
```

Each sublist has 6 elements, but lists are indexed from `0`

To get the 6th element, use `Cache[5][5]`

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are zero-indexed so, may be you can try following to access the last element i.e. fifth row and sixth element:

```
print(Cache[4][5])
```